# Hello How can i call java program by executing the servlet program

Tags: java, servlets

I have to execute the java program which is in the same package where when i execute servlet program i have to execute the java program where i used jsp to call servlet but now i am not able to execute java program

Comment: I'm afraid you're not explaining your problem very well. Are you trying to call the code in a Java class from a servlet? A servlet is a java class so there is no difference to standard Java. Are you trying to call an external program? Please detail your problem, providing your code or any error you encounter.

Comment: what i am trying to do is 1)I have written a program to convert pdf to text file in java so now i am implementing that into web application so i have designed jsp page so i have to execute my java program once i clicked button in jsp so now i have called servlet but i am not executing the java program so please give me any code snniptes and explain

Comment: i have to run java program by using servlet

Comment: I think I understand your question, but could you please break it down into short phrases or sentences?

Comment: I have to run the separate java program By using servlet program because i have used button in jsp so when i clicked on it it must execute java program with the help of servlet